# Screenscraping an App running inside an Emulator

Tags: android, screen-scraping

I'm running software that will attach to a window and periodically screenscrape what's inside it. This works well for all normal processes, however I am trying to screenscrape an App that is running inside an emulator on my PC.

When it scrapes the screen it just scrapes a black space of the Emulator and not the App running inside it.

Is there possibly a way around this? some program that can communicate it, or software that mirrors what is running in the Emulator which can then be scraped?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emulator screen capture button to capture only the emulator's buffer, and use it to embed its picture in the overall host screen capture.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, but I'm not sure how to specifically go about doing this. Could you let me know please?